# Spring WebFlow mysterious question mark

Tags: spring-webflow

Does anyone know what the question mark means in the "bookingService.findBookings(currentUser?.name)" part?

```
<view-state id="enterSearchCriteria">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="bookingService.findBookings(currentUser?.name)" result="viewScope.bookings" result-type="dataModel" />
    </on-render>
    <transition on="search" to="reviewHotels"/>
    <transition on="cancelBooking">
        <evaluate expression="bookingService.cancelBooking(bookings.selectedRow)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

And here is the method in the service class:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Booking> findBookings(String username) {
        if (username != null) {
            return em.createQuery("select b from Booking b where b.user.username = :username order by b.checkinDate").setParameter("username", username).getResultList();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The current user is I assume the person currently logged in to the app, but the snippet comes from a page where a user has not logged in yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks to be the "safe navigation operator".  If currentUser is null, then an access attempt to currentUser?.name will not cause an error (null pointer).